# Print NumPy Array based on header

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, numpy

I have a csv file with some data, here is a sample:

```
Alcohol,Malice acid,Ash,Alcalinity of ash,Magnesium,Total phenols,Flavanoids,Nonflavanoid phenols,Proanthocyanins,Color intensity,Hue,OD280/OD315 of diluted wines,Proline
1,14.23,1.71,2.43,15.6,127,2.8,3.06,0.28,2.29,5.64,1.04,3.92
1,13.2,1.78,2.14,11.2,100,2.65,2.76,0.26,1.28,4.38,1.05,3.4
1,13.16,2.36,2.67,18.6,101,2.8,3.24,0.3,2.81,5.68,1.03,3.17
```

I read in my csv file and I convert the arrays to 3 numpy arrays:

```
wine_data_file = open("wine.csv","r")

wine_data_reader = csv.reader(wine_data_file, delimiter=",")

wine_data = []
wine_labels = []
wine_columns = []

#Read each line of wine.csv
count = 0
for row in wine_data_reader:

    if count <= 0:
        wine_columns += [row[1:]]
    else:
        wine_labels += [int(row[0])]
        wine_data += [map(float,row[1:])]
    count = count + 1

wine_data = np.array(wine_data,dtype=float)
wine_labels = np.array(wine_labels)
wine_columns = np.array(wine_columns)
```

These numpy arrays will hold the column headers, the labels (the first number of each row), and the data.

I am able to print this result:

```
print wine_data[wine_labels == 1]
```

Which would get me every row in wine_data that had a label(Alcohol) of 1. However I am not able to do the same with this:

```
print wine_data[wine_columns == "Hue"]
```

My Question is, how able to get just every index in my numpy array at Hue.

Desired Outcome:

```
[[5.64],[4.38],[5.68]]
```

Comment: What have you tried? Give us some info please!

Comment: I think you would like pandas.

Comment: @PauloScardine I have to use a numpy array, it's for a school assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's first consider why

```
print wine_data[wine_labels == 1]
```

works. `wine_labels == 1` evaluates to `[ True  True  True]`, which means that you select every single one of the three rows in your `wine_data` array.

When you try to evaluate

```
print wine_data[wine_columns == "Hue"]
```

then the filter `wine_columns == "Hue"` evaluates to `[[False False False False False False False False False  True False False]]`. Note the double brackets: `wine_columns` is a two-dimensional array with one row and 12 columns. This makes it tricky to use it as a selector for the `wine_data` array.

So let's make this array one-dimensional: `(wine_columns == "Hue")[0]` is `[False False False False False False False False False  True False False]`. Now we want to use this as a selector for the columns in `wine_data`, and we also want any row:

```
print wine_data[:,(wine_columns == "Hue")[0]]
```

gives

```
[[ 5.64], [ 4.38], [ 5.68]]
```

which is what you want, but remember that it is still a two-dimensional array (3 rows, 1 column).

Answer (score 1):

Data is two dimensional, and you are applying a Boolean index to the 1st dimension. Instead, you want to apply it to the second dimension...

```
#columns ----------|
#rows-----|        |
#         V        V
wine_data[:,wine_columns == 'Hue']
```